# Using BizTalk to process files with differet formats

Tags: mapping, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have some incoming files with 2 different formats.

Is there a way I can route the different files to use the appropriate map in BizTalk?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of formats are you talking about? If this is XML or flat file (text-based) it is easy to determine the file type. If you are talking about something binary (PDF, Excel 2003, etc...) then things can become more complicated.

Please elaborate on which formats you are talking about.

To be short, BizTalk maps in receive and send ports rely on the context property BTS.MessageType to determine what the input format is and can then determine which mapping to execute.

What you would need to do:

- Create the schemas for all formats in Visual Studio.
- Create your mappings for both formats.
- Deploy your schemas DLL in your BizTalk application
- Create a receive location for your input files (I suppose it is one folder for both formats?)
- Use the XMLReceive pipeline for your receive location. This has a XML Disassembler pipeline component which will recognize the format and try to match it to your input formats.
- Configure your mappings on the receive port.
- Create a send port that subscribes to your receive port.

Hope this suits your needs.

Comment: they are xml files with different schemas. so basically what I want to know is how to drive xml file A though one mapping and then drive xml file B through a different mapping. thanks

Comment: @femi (sorry for formatting badly, newline issues)  

- Create the schemas for all formats in Visual Studio.  
- Create your mappings for both formats.  
- Deploy your schemas DLL in your BizTalk application  
- Create a receive location for your input files (I suppose it is one folder for both formats?)  
- Use the XMLReceive pipeline for your receive location. This has a XML Disassembler pipeline component which will recognize the format and try to match it to your input formats.  
- Configure your mappings on the receive port.  
- Create a send port that subscribes to your receive port.

Comment: Just to add a little further to Pieter's comment (Pieter stick it in your answer!) you will need to deploy your Maps to BizTalk and both maps can be applied to the single Receive Port - BizTalk will figure out which map to use after the Xml Disassembler in the XmlReceive Pipeline has figured out which schema the message is associated with.

Comment: @NickHeppleston thank you! I'm quite new to stack overflow to be honest (as you probably can tell).